# python server trafic listening

Tags: python, html, server

I've been trying to monitor server traffic using this Python code.

```
import socket, subprocess, os, sys


s = socket.socket()

host = socket.gethostname()
ip = socket.gethostbyname('127.0.0.1')
port = 80
s.bind((ip,port))
s.listen(5)
while True: 
    c, a = s.accept()
    fr = c.recv(1024)
    c.sendall(fr)
    print("IP: "+str(a[0])+":"+str(a[1])+"\tCONNECTED")
    c.close()
```

Everything is working fine, but I need to send the visitors to my homepage. but I have no idea how to do that. As in the code, I am sending the buffer data to the client. Help me on this, please. Thanks!

And I tried using get request in the sendall function, but it didn't work.